# Creating a method that returns a string

Tags: java

So far my code looks like this:

```
public class Tree {
  public static void main (String[] argv) {
    int serial; //create parameters
    double circumference;
    String species;      
  }
  public Tree(int serial, double circumference, String species) {
    String.format("Tree number %d has a circumference of %.2f and is of species %s.", 
        serial, circumference, species);
  }  
}
```

I'm not sure how I go about making a `describe()` method that returns a `String` with the tree information in a very specific format.

Comment: Sorry but your code is ugly code, meaning it is poorly formatted making it very hard to read. It makes sense, at least to me, that if you put some effort into formatting your code better, using reasonable and consistent indentation and minimal but appropriate use of white space (one blank line is enough), more folks will be able to read and understand your code and then help you. Please believe me, it is effort well spent.

Comment: String[] result = myTreeSet.toArray(new String[myTreeSet.size()]);

then convert as String

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to put the describe method code into the Tree constructor. Don't do that. Use the constructor to initialize your fields, then then create your describe method that returns the formatted String.

```
public class Tree {
  // private Tree fields go here

  public Tree(int serial, double circumference, String species) {
    // initialize the Tree fields here
  }

  public String describe() {
    // return your formatted String describing the current Tree object here
  }
}
```

As an aside, your main method really doesn't do anything useful, and certainly does not create any instances of Tree that would allow you to test the describe method.

Answer (score 1):

The method `String.format` returns a `String` already

```
public String describe(){
      return String.format("Tree number %d has a circumference of %.2f and is of species %s.", serial, circumference, species);
}
```

I would suggest you to override `toString()` method to provide meaningful information about the object

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Tree number %d has a circumference of %.2f and is of species %s.", serial, circumference, species);
}
```